# how to count two string common character

Tags: javascript, node.js

*** i am try to this count two string match character ***

```
var s1 = "abcd";
var s2 = "aad";
function match(s1,s2){
    var obj = {}
    var spilt1 = s1.split("")
    var spilt2 = s2.split("")

    for(let i =0;i<spilt1.length;i++){
        let th = spilt2.includes(spilt1[i])
        if(!obj[th[i]]){
            obj[th[i]] = 0

        }else{
           obj[th[i]]++
        }

    }
    return obj
}
console.log(match(s1,s2))
```

*** output like this ***
**{
a:1,
d:1
}**

Comment: What is your question? What in the above code is not working?

Comment: count two common string character in formate object

Answer (score 0):

```
function match(str1, str2) {
const str1Obj = {};
const resultObj = {};

for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) { 
    str1Obj[str1[i]] = str1Obj.hasOwnProperty(str1[i])
        ? str1Obj[str1[i]] + 1
        : 1;
}

for (let i = 0; i < str2.length; i++) {
    if (str1Obj.hasOwnProperty(str2[i]) && str1Obj[str2[i]] >= 1) {
        resultObj[str2[i]] = resultObj.hasOwnProperty(str2[i])
            ? resultObj[str2[i]] + 1
            : 1;
        str1Obj[str2[i]] -= 1;
    }
}
return resultObj;
```

}